# Narrow down type of callback Parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a function:

```js
type Callback = (data: Record<string, unknown>) => void
const execCb = (cb: Callback) => {
  cb(somedata)
}
```

As you can see, data is pretty generic because it could be any object. However, when I define my callbacks, I would like to narrow down the data to specific types:

```js
type MyCallBackData = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number
}
const myCallback = (data: MyCallBackData) => {
  // do something
}

execCb(myCallback)
```

Typescript complains, that `Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'MyCallBackData': foo, bar`

How can I properly narrow down a type in this case?

Plaground: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBQAmcwcAXFAEoRoD2ATgQDwDOwdAlgHYDmANFAFdOGTjQDunAHwBKHJKgA3GuwIAoVbU6soEAB7UYyHPjTJy8JKkyzs8gN6qoUU3jsBfaarfrQkKAFkQCwQAIXQMABFiOGMHJwAzGhpyVg4eXkcoVDpyTgEAW2QIOi91TW18oMQUcONCaPJA4LDMKJIbe0yAei6oAhooZhp8iGAACy5uUtU9A2Q8SuCrDGkgA)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `Record<string, unknown>`, means you can pass in a object with no properties (like you do, where you pass `{}`) but the callback you pass in requires proeprties on the first argument. So this is not type safe.

What you could do is make `execCb` generic, so the parameter can be any type. THis also means you won't be able to pass in a concrete object in `execCb` (at least not without a type assertion). You can for example pass it as an extra parameter to `execCb`.

```
type Callback<T> = (data: T) => void

const execCb = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(cb: Callback<T>, param: T) => {
  cb(param)
}

type MyCallBackData = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number
}

const myCallback = (data: MyCallBackData) => {
  // do something
}

execCb(myCallback, {
  foo: "",
  bar: 1
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYB4AqA+KAXigAoATOYOALihwEoiCA3AewEsyAoLtVgOwDOwKBAAeENDGREouUWOAR+ZQVABKk1gCcyWYdvb8A5gBooAV34Z+rAO788eEmmS14SVJlx5zYONpwALa0DExQAN5cUFCuJP6BQfRcAL48oJBQALIgHggAQugYACKUcLJRMQBmrKy0BkZm0VCo2rT8FkHIENqpPHxCIkG5iChFsuRltDl5hZilVIyEBJVQAPRrUGSsUIKsQRDAABaNfVziktIkw3leGOarNXVQAEQvps2ttACMqfRAA)

Comment: What I know about the object bering passed to the callback is, that it is always a record. I also can assure programmatically that the desired properties are defined for every callback. However I don't know how to tell typescript "I know that this parameters are correct and have everything this callback desires".